# How to get the position of the cursor on the screen？

Tags: javascript

I need to get the position of the cursor in an editable div (quill rich text) for the whole screen, but I don't know how to do it and would like some help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j08N1.png)

Comment: With "_cursor_" you mean caret? There's no such measure property (presented in the image) for the caret, but you can get the offset from the start, or the element under the caret and a couple of other values, see [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) for details.

Comment: var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  properties...
});


quill.focus()

Answer (score 1):

[mousemove event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I didn't make myself clear I've added a diagram, please take a look thank you